# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in angular 2

Tags: angular, selenium

We want to auto form filling in client side for my angular 2 application.
for this we use selenium-webdriver but we facing following error.

```
Failed to compile.

./~/selenium-webdriver/net/portprober.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'D:\AngularJS\Template\CoreUI-Free-Bootstrap-Admin-Template-master\Angular4_CLI_Full_Project\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\net'
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/net/portprober.js 20:11-35
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/index.js
 @ ./src/app/icons/font-awesome.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/icons/icons.module.ts
 @ ./src async
 @ ./~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

My sample code using typescript

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Builder, By, until } from 'selenium-webdriver';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'font-awesome.component.html'
})
export class FontAwesomeComponent {

    constructor() {
        var driver = new Builder()
            .forBrowser('chrome')
            .build();  
        driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
        driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
        driver.findElement(By.name('btnG')).click();
        driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000);
        console.log('Done!');
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

I am able to run using command: node myfile.js

Comment: could you give me solution of following question?